# How to add "/1/" as a line number in a txt file?

Tags: shell, file, unix, line

In Unix I want to add slash before and after the line number in a .txt file

this command only shows the line numbers
    cat -n txt.file

this:

```
Tony
Alpha
Bravo
```

to this:

```
/1/ Tony
/2/ Alpha
/3/ Bravo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print "/" FNR "/ " $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

[awk is probably the cleanest option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008022/2998), but you can also use the `nl` command:

```
 nl -a -n ln txt.file | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\) */\/\1\//'
```

(The slashes around the line number -- homework question? -- complicates it. The sed command adds the slashes. You may need to edit it slightly depending on your version of Unix. I did this on a Mac.)

Comment: That `sed` might be more readable with `-E`: `sed -E 's|^([0-9]*) *|/\1/|'`

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution is:

```
   sed '=' file | sed 'N;s_^_/_;s_\n_/ _'
```

One needs a pipe `|` here because of the limitations of the `=` command.

Answer (score 1):

To throw in a `bash` solution (slow as expected):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do printf '/%d/ %s\n' "$((++i))" "$line"; done < file.txt
```

Or a strange but "creative" way (surprisingly it is relatively fast):

```
paste -d" " <(seq -f "/%g/" 1 $(wc -l < file.txt)) file.txt
```

Comment: Not sure if the second one is neat or horrific ;)

Comment: @StephenDarlington I believe it's the latter :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution

```
$ cat  add_line_num.txt
Tony
Alpha
Bravo

$ perl -pe ' $_="/$./ $_" ' add_line_num.txt
/1/ Tony
/2/ Alpha
/3/ Bravo
```